How to treat right-censoring data when fitting survival model and check the model goodness-of-fit?
I'm trying to build a survival model using parametric proportional hazard (PH). In this R package, I have prepared several methods (such as generating random survival data for single continuous covariate/marker, MLE estimation, checking goodness-of-fit etc.). When doing simulation study for the PH model, I do not encounter any problem when fitting the simulated data. The MLE function still return a reasonable parameter estimate when simulated data is right-censored. In figure below, when simulating a normal marker with Weibull time-to-event, the MLE estimation for time-to-event still return a reasonable estimate with acceptable goodness-of-fit, GOF (theoretically for time variable, Cox-Snell residual will follow Exponential distribution with rate 1) with p-value for Kolmogorov-Smirnov test greater than significance level of 0.05.
test <- timeroc_obj("normal-weibull-PH")
jj <- rtimeroc(test, n=500, censor.rate = 0.1,
               params.x = c(mean = 5, sd = 0.8),
               params.t = c(shape = 1.6, scale = 2.4),
               params.ph = 0.5)
cc <- timeroc_fit(test, x = jj$x, t = jj$t,
                  event = jj$event)
cc
Model:  normal-weibull-PH 
------
X (95% CI) :
AIC =  1198.314 
        est    low  upper     se
mean 4.9911 4.9210 5.0611 0.0357
sd   0.7988 0.7493 0.8483 0.0253
------
Time-to-Event (95% CI) :
AIC =  1357.605 
         est    low  upper     se
shape 1.5964 1.4805 1.7124 0.0591
scale 3.4058 2.1500 4.6615 0.6407
------
PH (95% CI) :
        est    low  upper     se
beta 0.5867 0.4641 0.7094 0.0626

timeroc_gof(cc)


However, when applying this model using real data (such as mayo data from 'survivalROC'), it seems that the MLE estimation is unable to produce estimates with appropriate goodness-of-fit. I bet this is due to the censored data because when I remove them during fitting process, the goodness-of-fit improves.
This is the GOF when including right-censor data. If we generate random data using the MLE estimates, then overlay it with the mayo data, we can see the real data only concentrated on certain part of the estimated joint distribution. And this also support why we obtain KS-statistic with very low p-value.
library(survivalROC)
data(mayo)
# still assuming normal marker, weibull time-to-event model.
cc <- timeroc_fit(test, x = mayo$mayoscore5, t = mayo$time, event = mayo$censor)
timeroc_gof(cc)


rr <- rtimeroc(test, n=1000,
               params.x = cc$x$par,
               params.t = cc$t$par[-length(cc$t$par)],
               params.ph = cc$t$par[length(cc$t$par)])
p1 <- ggplot(rr, aes(x = x, y = t, color = 'simulated')) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
p1 + geom_point(data = mayo, aes(x = mayoscore5, y = time, color = "mayo")) +
  labs(color = 'Data')


Meanwhile, this is the GOF when excluding right-censor data. When generating the random data many times using the estimated parameter, the real data seems to overlap with the estimated joint distribution. And this is also supported with the p-value of the KS test (0.9675) that is greater than significance level of 0.05.
mayo <- mayo[which(mayo$censor == 1),]
cc <- timeroc_fit(test, x = mayo$mayoscore5, t = mayo$time, event = mayo$censor)
timeroc_gof(cc)


rr <- rtimeroc(test, n=1000,
               params.x = cc$x$par,
               params.t = cc$t$par[-length(cc$t$par)],
               params.ph = cc$t$par[length(cc$t$par)])
p1 <- ggplot(rr, aes(x = x, y = t, color = 'simulated')) + geom_point() + theme_bw()
data(mayo)
p1 + geom_point(data = mayo, aes(x = mayoscore5, y = time, color = "mayo")) +
  labs(color = 'Data')


My question is that, why this is happening? Although right-censored data still provide a useful information, should I consider the right-censored data when estimating my model? Or is there a way that can guarantee us to obtain parameter with good fit?
As a side note, in the MLE process, I used the standard step when calculating the likelihood for time-to-event which is:
$$ L(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^{n} f(t_i|x)^{\delta_i}\times S(t_i|x)^{1-\delta_i}$$
